Aristotle definition of irony
Several internet sources quote Aristotle describing irony as “dissembling toward the inner core of truth.”  I wonder if this is an elegantly worded butchery of Nicomachean Ethics 1108a20.  But it would be great if there is a legitimate source for the quote.  Is there?
